# How do I encrypt a dual boot system?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, hard-drive, security, encryption

I have a dual-boot laptop with four partitions - `Windows`, `swap`, `Ubuntu (OS)` and`Ubuntu /home`. I need to do full disk encryption on it. Ubuntu is running 12.04, Windows is Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: There's some relevant discussion over on security: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14227/multi-boot-with-full-hard-drive-encryption-and-pre-boot-authentication

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/a/293029/207933

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see how to avoid to handle Windows and Ubuntu separately using software.

- TrueCrypt for Windows installation. For example this ["How To Use TrueCrypt To Encrypt The Whole Windows System"](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2012/01/how-to-use-truecrypt-to-encrypt-the-whole-windows-system/).
- Install Ubuntu using the alternate installer image. I recommend you to use LVM as it makes it possible to have all partitions (then LVs) in one dm-crypt container. It requires a `/boot` partition but LVM saves you from more. See this article how to do that: ["How to install Ubuntu 11.04 on an encrypted LVM file system"](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/10/how-to-install-ubuntu-11-04-on-an-encrypted-lvm-file-system/) (while a bit old, still relevant for 12.04).

Alternatively, get yourself an expensive [Self Encrypting Hard Drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-based_full_disk_encryption) unlocked by your BIOS at boot time, if supported. This way, no configuration is required by your OS and all processing (encrypting/decrypting) is done by the hard drive instead of your CPU.

Comment: I ended up just doing FDE for the whole drive, and virtualizing my Windows box.