# 13.04 :: setting up hibernate + encryped swap under full disk encryption

Tags: 13.04, encryption, hibernate, swap

So I recently installed 13.04 and chose full disk encryption (I didn't bother to encrypt home too - seemed pointless), and I'm wanting to encrypt my swap drive, and also enable hibernate so I can be as secure as possible. I haven't been able to find much information that pertains to my exact set of circumstances, and although I found this webpage (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap), it says it has only been tested with 12.04.

In any case, I went ahead and tried that and once I got to step 6 under "How to setup hibernation", I got an error stating that:

```
swapon: /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: read swap header failed: Invalid argument
```

I don't know if I've FUBARED it or if a few commands can fix it, it doesn't really matter because I did all of this on a fresh install and there is no files I'm worried about losing.

Can anyone help me get this working?

Comment: Does this help? [How can I install Ubuntu encrypted with LUKS with dual-boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/293028)

Comment: Possibly this guide to install **Tux on Ice** could be solution for you: http://askubuntu.com/a/356289/58470

Comment: Similar setup, using `uswsusp`: [Encrypted home partition + encrypted swap + working hibernate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/396136/encrypted-home-encrypted-swap-working-hibernate)