# Cannot decrypt hardrive. Password not accepted

Tags: boot, password, encryption, lvm, initramfs

I have been tackling this for at least 5 days now. Initially I couldn't get Ubuntu to recognise my already installed partition LVM with an Arch, Home, and Swap logical volume. I have now got Ubuntu installed in another logical volume with the help of this guide:

[How can I install Ubuntu encrypted with LUKS with dual-boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot)

Here is my partition layout in case it helps going forward:

http://pastebin.com/MumsXSUu

I managed to get it to boot yesterday and done the latest updates to 14.04. After rebooting Ubuntu replaced my Arch grub (not intended - I will uninstall Ubuntu grub if I can get the system to boot again) and would not boot the encrypted partition, it wouldn't accept my password. I used the Arch ISO to put the Arch Grub back into place, however this doesn't boot either. I have used the old kernel and initramfs (3.13.0-19) and the new updated one (3.13.0-24) and neither accept my password. However the same password works to decrypt Arch Linux.

I have tried using the US keyboard (I know where the differences are to my UK keyboard) and the password isn't accepted in that form either so it is not due to a US layout now being used. I am at the end here of getting this to work but I am now so close to giving up. I cannot see why my password would be rejected. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you for even just reading this and any help you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. I went onto my Arch Linux install and used *lsmod* to find any encryption related kernel modules that I may be missing. I found *twofish_common* and *twofish_generic* (I am using the twofish cipher) and added these both to my initramfs. It now works.

I find this very weird because it worked prior to the update and these modules were not specified. Oh well I got it to work now. Many thanks to anyone who had a look and may have tried to figure out what was going on!