# Custom encrypted partitions using 16.04

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, luks

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop using [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot). I have an unencrypted boot partition and a separate LVM partition which contains my root, home and swap partitions. If I boot from a live USB, I can decrypt the partition and mount the drives with no problem, but otherwise I'm dumped to the initramfs prompt with an message saying the LVM volume group cannot be found - there has been no attempt to decrypt the LUKS partition which contains the VG.

My question is, how can I troubleshoot this to see what step I have either done wrong or missed out? The guide is for a previous version but I assume not much has changed? I'm sure I have followed the guide properly.

My reason for not using the defaults within Ubiquity, is because I want a separate home partition.

I'm installing on a latop with an SSD.

Thanks