# Installing linux as secondary OS on encrypted PC

Tags: encryption

So I have this Windows 10 PC encrypted with [Vera Crypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/). Are there any caveats If I'd want to install Ubuntu on dual boot? Or the installation process would be the same as usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Vera Crypt, but given you have a free partition, you can install it there perfectly fine. It's just the partition will not be encrypted anymore, but [you can enable encryption in Ubuntu either](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot).

However, if you have a single encrypted partition, and want to break it to two, then everything gets harder. You could probably try reduce the partition size straight with `gparted`, but it is likely to destroy your data, because it have no way to know where are files resides on the encrypted partition. [There is a VeraCryptExpander](https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/general/thread/c011ff54/#8046), but I'm not sure if it can reduce encrypted partition too, or only expand.

So, if you want to break up a single encrypted partition to two, the simplest way would probably be

1. [Remove encryption](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Removing%20Encryption)
2. Reduce partition size
3. Create a new partition from the freed size
4. Encrypt the partition back.