# Ubuntu dual-boot with LVM and LUKS install fails

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, encryption, lvm

I have a HP Pavilion G7 laptop with UEFI support and a 250GB GPT SSD disk. Laptop initially had Windows 8 installed, but later I made a Windows 10 clean install and reserved some empty space for linux.

Now I want to have Win10 & Ubuntu16 Mate 16.04 LTS dualboot, LUKS encrypted disks with LVM.

This kind of dualboot confuguration with LUKS and LVM is not possible with Ubuntu Mate GUI installer, but I found following instructions to follow (tested for Ubuntu 13.04):

[How can I install Ubuntu encrypted with LUKS with dual-boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot)

I tried to follow these instructions but always when booting I cannot open the encrypted disk because `cryptsetup` fails.

Here is my procedure, numbering is same as in instructions:

1. Boot from an Ubuntu live DVD or USB stick, and select "Try Ubuntu".
2. Create partitions using GParted included in the live disk. 
   GParted. Created 2 partitions: boot and data for LUKS. Windows esp will be used for Ubuntu also.

   ```
   (parted) print list                                                       
   Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
   Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
   Partition Table: gpt
   Disk Flags: 

   Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
    1      1049kB  473MB  472MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
    2      473MB   578MB  105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
    3      578MB   595MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
    4      595MB   123GB  123GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
    5      123GB   124GB  835MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag
    6      124GB   125GB  524MB   ext4         NotUsed
    7      125GB   126GB  1049MB  ext4         linux-boot
    8      126GB   250GB  124GB                linux-data

   ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ lsblk
   NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
   sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
   ├─sda1   8:1    0   450M  0 part 
   ├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part (This is Windows esp)
   ├─sda3   8:3    0    16M  0 part 
   ├─sda4   8:4    0 114.4G  0 part 
   ├─sda5   8:5    0   796M  0 part 
   ├─sda6   8:6    0   500M  0 part 
   ├─sda7   8:7    0  1000M  0 part (boot)
   └─sda8   8:8    0 115.7G  0 part (LUKS)
   ```

   format partitions sda7, sda8
3. Create a LUKS container using these commands

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda8
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda8 pv_data
   ```
4. It is critical to properly initialize the new LUKS container

   ```
   ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/pv_data bs=16M
   dd: error writing '/dev/mapper/pv_data': No space left on device
   7469+0 records in
   7468+0 records out
   125303783424 bytes (125 GB, 117 GiB) copied, 381.69 s, 328 MB/s
   ```
5. Inside the mounted LUKS container, create an LVM physical volume, a volume group and two logical volumes. The first logical volume will be mounted at /, and the second one will be used as swap.

   ```
   ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ sudo pvcreate /dev/mapper/pv_data
     Physical volume "/dev/mapper/pv_data" successfully created

   ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ sudo vgcreate vg_data /dev/mapper/pv_data
     Volume group "vg_data" successfully created

   ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ sudo lvcreate -n lv_swap -L 12g vg_data
     Logical volume "lv_swap" created.

   ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ sudo lvcreate -n lv_root -L 80g vg_data
     Logical volume "lv_root" created.

   ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ lsblk
   NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
   sda                     8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk  
   ...
   └─sda8                  8:8    0 115.7G  0 part  
   └─pv_data           252:0    0 115.7G  0 crypt 
       ├─vg_data-lv_swap 252:1    0    12G  0 lvm   
       └─vg_data-lv_root 252:2    0    80G  0 lvm
   ```
6. Create filesystems for the two logical volumes

   ```
   ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_root
   mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
   Creating filesystem with 20971520 4k blocks and 5242880 inodes
   Filesystem UUID: 1cbd1ea6-fa20-41f6-a870-5c159301bee4
   Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
   32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
   4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000

   Allocating group tables: done                            
   Writing inode tables: done                            
   Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
   Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done   

   ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_swap
   Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 12 GiB (12884897792 bytes)
   no label, UUID=d665e5d7-b81f-4078-a5d5-bb1dd137fce2
   ```
7. Install Ubuntu using the graphical installer, choosing manual partitioning.

   Assign: `/` to `/dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_root`, `/boot` to `/dev/sda7`, swap to `/dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_swap`

   mark other partitions "do not use" except sda7 boot, lv_root, lv_swap, sda2 efi windows boot manager

   Select device for bootloader installation to `/dev/sda`
8. Once the graphical installer is finished, select "continue testing" and open a terminal.
9. Find the UUID of the LUKS partitions: `/dev/sda8`

   ```
   ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ sudo blkid
   /dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="FABE4708BE46BCBF" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="69ee7fd0-ed56-41b2-b974-b76647cb98d5"
   /dev/sda2: UUID="9A47-7CB4" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="3cfbb43a-3bfd-48ac-b673-109f469c4d72"
   /dev/sda4: UUID="82324D05324D0021" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="342a1cfb-8587-4dbc-a180-4872aa23aff5"
   /dev/sda5: UUID="D606B52306B50611" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="6bebe835-96b9-422e-b9c1-baf69ae085b3"
   /dev/sda6: UUID="341a01d8-dcb7-4c51-99aa-22a84d53054b" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="NotUsed" PARTUUID="f2524ea7-8736-4998-8705-5e9d22c42b3c"
   /dev/sda7: UUID="d0033e81-c785-4efc-a0d3-1128b7a99792" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="linux-boot" PARTUUID="08e453f9-84ca-48b0-a26f-915f2462c578"
   /dev/sdb1: LABEL="UBUNTU-MATE" UUID="8EDE-65EA" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Microsoft Basic Data" PARTUUID="2c0f92b3-5d67-45c7-bc1b-ce8a1a284015"
   /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
   /dev/sda8: UUID="ec4c6b1d-0bf1-41d4-81ec-754987a5532f" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTLABEL="linux-data" PARTUUID="18bf1837-1dda-477a-9007-e3478e12f565"
   /dev/sdc1: LABEL="FAT32GB" UUID="FE56-878C" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="58ee1847-01"
   /dev/mapper/pv_data: UUID="11kz5r-WtT9-c2oU-sDrB-ObWm-OCiP-t0JG9c" TYPE="LVM2_member"
   /dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_swap: UUID="d665e5d7-b81f-4078-a5d5-bb1dd137fce2" TYPE="swap"
   /dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_root: UUID="57c480e3-59c7-4203-ac5c-2a08075fd71c" TYPE="ext4"
   /dev/dm-1: UUID="d665e5d7-b81f-4078-a5d5-bb1dd137fce2" TYPE="swap"
   /dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="dfbb8924-81a1-4646-9baa-3a4977641f5e"
   ```
10. Mount the appropriate devices to the appropriate locations in /mnt, and chroot into it:

    ```
    sudo mount /dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_root /mnt
    sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt/boot
    sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
    sudo chroot /mnt
    ```
11. Create a file named /etc/crypttab in the chrooted environment:

    ```
    root@ubuntu-mate:/# cat /etc/crypttab
    # <target name> <source device> <key file> <options>
    pv_data UUID=ec4c6b1d-0bf1-41d4-81ec-754987a5532f none luks,retry=1,lvm=vg_data
    ```
12. Create a file named /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/cryptroot in the chrooted environment:

    ```
    root@ubuntu-mate:/# cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/cryptroot
    CRYPTROOT=target=pv_data,source=/dev/disk/by-uuid/ec4c6b1d-0bf1-41d4-81ec-754987a5532f
    ```
13. Run the following command in the chrooted environment:

    ```
    root@ubuntu-mate:/# update-initramfs -k all -c
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic
    cat: /proc/cmdline: No such file or directory
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
    cat: /proc/cmdline: No such file or directory
    ```

    Are these errors critical?
14. Edit the file named /etc/default/grub in the chrooted envirnoment:

    ```
    root@ubuntu-mate:/# cat /etc/default/grub
    # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
    # /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
    # For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
    #   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

    GRUB_DEFAULT=0
    #GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
    GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
    GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
    GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
    #GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptopts=target=pv_data,source=/dev/disk/by-uuid/ec4c6b1d-0bf1-41d4-81ec-754987a5532f,lvm=vg_data"

    # Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
    # This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
    # the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
    #GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

    # Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
    #GRUB_TERMINAL=console

    # The resolution used on graphical terminal
    # note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
    # you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
    #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

    # Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
    #GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

    # Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
    #GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

    # Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
    #GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
    root@ubuntu-mate:/#
    ```
15. Run the following command in the chrooted environment:

    ```
    root@ubuntu-mate:/# update-grub
    Generating grub configuration file ...
    ...
    /proc/devices: fopen failed: No such file or directory
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic
    /proc/devices: fopen failed: No such file or directory
    device node not found
    /proc/devices: fopen failed: No such file or directory
    device node not found
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
    Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
    /proc/devices: fopen failed: No such file or directory
    /proc/devices: fopen failed: No such file or directory
    /proc/devices: fopen failed: No such file or directory
    device node not found
    ...
    device node not found
    /proc/devices: fopen failed: No such file or directory
    device node not found
    Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
    Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
    grep: /proc/mounts: No such file or directory
    Cannot find list of partitions!  (Try mounting /sys.)
    done
    root@ubuntu-mate:/#
    ```

    Dozens of `device node not found` errors removed here, is it normal that update-grub produces this many errors?
16. Reboot and boot into the encrypted Ubuntu. You should be prompted for a password.

    During the reboot, Windows 10 starts to boot by default. If I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and select Ubuntu from list, Ubuntu starts booting but `cryptsetup` fails with following error messages:

    ```
    cryptsetup: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?
    /scripts/local-top/cryptroot: line:1 /sbin/cryptsetup: not found.
    ```

What's the reason for this failure and how can I fix it?

`/etc/modules` file is empty. Should there be something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got time to fix this.

Error was in step 10. I missed this part of it:

```
mount -t proc proc /proc
mount -t sysfs sys /sys
mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts
```

After fixing that, installation went fine.

Other notes concerning the [referenced answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot):

- Author has modified the answer so that if you read all the comments saying that you can skip steps 12,14,15 you go WRONG. Modifications take these comments into account and these steps are already removed from instructions, so do not skip any steps.
- I installed Ubuntu Mate LTS 16.4.1 with those instructions.

I also noticed that **it is actually possible to install dual boot with LUKS encrypted partition without exiting the Ubuntu installer GUI**. The downsize of this option is that you can only make 1 encrypted partition. So with GUI installer you can have a configuration like this:

- non-crypted boot
- encrypted root

and then create swapfile inside the encrypted root if needed with [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04)