# How to create dual boot with LUKS/LVM full partition encryption on same disk?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, encryption, luks

I followed this tutorial from 2014: https://www.oxygenimpaired.com/multiple-linux-distro-installs-on-a-luks-encrypted-harddrive

I am installing Linux Mint 19.1 XFCE and Ubuntu 18.04, both fully encrypted in a single disk. First I installed Linux Mint on `/dev/sda5`.

After following all steps to install the first Linux, and rebooting the machine, I got into the [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox) with this error:

1. [image]

When following the tutorial, I ran the following commands:

1. `fdisk /dev/sda`, then, created the following partitions:

   - [image]
2. `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda5`
3. `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 sda5_crypt`
4. `pvcreate /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt`
5. `vgcreate vggroup /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt`
6. `lvcreate -L1G -n mint_xfce_swap vggroup`
7. `lvcreate -L8.9G -n mint_xfce_root vggroup`

   - [image]
8. `mkdir /mnt/newroot`
9. `mount /dev/mapper/[vg-name]-[root1-lv-name] /mnt/newroot`
10. `mount -o bind /proc /mnt/newroot/proc`
11. `mount -o bind /dev /mnt/newroot/dev`
12. `mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/newroot/dev/pts`
13. `mount -o bind /sys /mnt/newroot/sys`
14. `cd /mnt/newroot`
15. `chroot /mnt/newroot`
16. `mount /dev/sda1 /boot`
17. `blkid /dev/sda5`

    - [image]
    - [image]
    - [image]
18. `update-initramfs -u`
19. `update-grub`

    - [image]
    - [image]
20. `exit`
21. `reboot`

---

Other references:

1. [Ubuntu dual-boot with LVM and LUKS install fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834390/ubuntu-dual-boot-with-lvm-and-luks-install-fails)
2. [How can I install Ubuntu encrypted with LUKS with dual-boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot)