Emergency mode boot
I'm new both here and to Linux, but liking it aside from the learning curve but glad to be Windows free. I had an issue with Ubuntu 22.04 when I got home where my PC now boots in emergency mode. I'm not sure how to fix this and hoping for some help.
Initially this was due to a full disk I think. I managed to delete a few files from terminal to free space but it's still booting in emergency mode.
I've attached a few photos but I'm wondering if this is a fstab file issue where efi and grub aren't mounting maybe.
Emergency mode message:

/etc/fstab:

yes you are correct the drive is encrypted i enter code then get this.
i feel like i'm missing an entry in fstab but i haven't backed it up. i only have my boot nvme and a media device.

It looks like your computer has encrypted partitions. When you reboot your computer do you get the prompt to enter the pass-phrase or does it go into the Emergency mode before you enter the LUKs pass-phrase? Edit your question and add this information.

Your fstab shows the mount of some partition by UUID into /media. But no mount of / (root). Often /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root, but you may have set yours up differently, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128197/how-to-create-dual-boot-with-luks-lvm-full-partition-encryption-on-same-disk & https://askubuntu.com/questions/719409/how-to-reinstall-grub-from-a-liveusb-if-the-partition-is-encrypted-and-there-i?rq=1

Yes, I added the media drive by uuid for a media server setup, but the SSD was setup automatically when I setup Ubuntu initially. Do I need to simply find what the partitions are on my SSD, and add those back to my fstab? I can see all of the files within my SSD from root terminal, so it appears the drive is working fine, it just isn't loading the gui side of Ubuntu and asking for user login.

Bumping, not sure where to go from here, help much appreciated.

Oldfred, what would the fstab look like with LUKS in a LVM setup? Given that this was a default setup for the drive when I built the system, could I set a spare ssd on a fresh install and mimick my created fstab to repair the first?
