# Swap not working with lvm on luks

Tags: lvm, 16.10, luks

I've installed new Ubuntu 16.10 with LVM on LUKS using this instruction: (https://askubuntu.com/a/293029).
But when I type `swapon -s` I get:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition   3145724 0   -1
```

UPD:
Made the fresh install with standard options of encryption (erase disk, encrypt disk, use lvm). Swap still not working

Comment: Same issue in my case as well

Comment: The output you posted before the update shows you have a fully working swap partition of about 3gb, which remained unused at that moment...

Answer (score 1):

"Used 0" might be perfectly fine if you have plenty of RAM. In fact I have the same right now but sometimes when I use more memory things get swapped.

Comment: Now I use swap file instead of swap partition and it works