# Windows Ubuntu BitLocker LUKS UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I want to run Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.0.4 as dual boot with Windows being encrypted by BitLocker and Ubuntu with LUKS.  I have been able to achieve this on BIOS using following:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0b4I89LY5E

[How can I install Ubuntu encrypted with LUKS with dual-boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot)

But, somehow it does not work with UEFI with respect to Ubuntu.  I am facing issues with GRUB I suppose.  Initially I faced the issue of EFI Partition not found as guides are for BIOS-based solution.  But, then I created efi directory in /mnt/boot and mounted it against the EFI partition where Windows Boot Manager is installed.  After that I specified the Windows Boot Manager (EFI Partition) when running grub-install command and everything went fine without any errors.  But, when I reboot, I am given initramfs prompt.  So, quite not sure how to troubleshoot it.

Steps that are not in the guide and I have done are below:

```
mount /dev/mapper/ubu-root /mnt

mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot

mkdir -p /mnt/boot/efi

mount /dev/sda2 (Windows Boot Manager) /mnt/boot/efi

cd /mnt

mount --rbind /dev dev

mount --rbind /sys sys

mount --rbind /run run

mount --bind /proc proc

chroot . /bin/bash -l

blkid (to note down the UUID of /dev/sda6 (luks volume))

vi /etc/crypttab

sda6-crypt /dev/sda6 OR UUID  none  luks,discard

:wq

update-initramfs -u

grub-install --recheck /dev/sda2

grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

exit

cd

umount -l /mnt

sync

exit

exit
```

Any help would be appreciated?