# Ubuntu Encryption Options UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, encryption

I want to run Windows 10 (UEFI) and Ubuntu 16.0.4 (UEFI) as dual boot with Windows being encrypted by BitLocker and Ubuntu with whatever is best option.  So, essentially this question is about what is best option to encrypt your Ubuntu as well as how to do it.

1. What options are suggested?

   1. LUKS?
   2. Select the "Encrypt your Ubuntu installation for security" during setup
   3. Select "Encrypt /home?" during setup
   4. Use Physical Disk Encryption and forget encryption on OS level?
2. How are all four-4 above different from one another?
3. How to achieve them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is both broad and has been asked here many times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I looked at the link, it is for encryption after installation.  Can you just give one liners to above question, I would really appreciate it.  thanks.

Comment: The second answer in the link I gave you answers your questions under the "Here's a list of possible set-ups, depending on different security needs:"

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_encryption - whole disk in Ubuntu == LUKS. Home only is ecryptfs. You can use one or both depending on what you want. They both work fine and have little or nothing to do with UEFI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Appreciate it.  I am facing little issue with Grub when doing the LUKS through UEFI.  Through BIOS, it works fine.  But with UEFI, after install I only get initramfs prompt.  I have started another thread for that.  Would appreciate your input on that as well.

Comment: Just a supplementary question.  What sort of encryption is happening in the 2. of question 1.? The one we are prompted for when we installing?

Comment: link ? Run boot repair ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair ? Link from boot-repair ?

Comment: And what are your suggestion if SSD supports hardware level encryption.  Forget about doing it on OS and just do that Hardware level Encryption?

Comment: If your hardware does the encryption then it is OS independent and has nothing to do with Ubuntu or Windows. Not sure if your SSD hardware encryption is windows only or not, you would have to identify the hardware.

Comment: This is the link:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/858515/windows-ubuntu-bitlocker-luks-uefi

Comment: You are probably going to find google searches helpful - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Self-Encrypting_Drives

Comment: Would not  Boot Repair cause issues with Windows Boot Manager if I go ahead?         And is there any tool to verify if my SSD supports Hardware Encryption or not?  You have been a great help