# How to Increase the size of my Root Logical Volume in a partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, encryption, volume-control

I had to encrypt my Ubuntu for my job, but I also had to keep my dual boot due to some softwares that I absolutely need and can only run on Windows.

With that, I followed the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot) and [here](http://blog.botux.fr/en/2015/09/ubuntu-installation-manual-full-disk-encryption-lvm-on-luks/), which were very thorough instructions. However, when finishing my installation, I had very little space on my Linux partition.

I have a 1TB hard drive, where I set 400GB to Windows and 530GB to Ubuntu. However, when I checked, my Ubuntu has only 8GB of space, when I expected it to have 530GB

When I ran

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

I received the following [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJo23.png), where the key parts are here

```
Disk /dev/mapper/CryptDisk: 531.1 GiB, 570299514880 bytes, 1113866240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_ns-ns_root: 7.5 GiB, 8053063680 bytes, 15728640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_ns-ns_swap: 1 GiB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

And this is what it shows on GParted, where the `/dev/sda5` is the partition where I put my Ubuntu. 
[GParted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X03k.png)

I know people may have asked this before, but nothing seems to be working for me. How would I make it such that my Ubuntu does end up using all of the 530GB?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found [Tecmint's guide](https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/) to do so. I guess I didn't know what to search for.
"How to Extend/Reduce Logical Volume Management"

Since the partition is encrypted, a lot of the commands had to be run as a super-user, but besides that, it works!