# Not sure of /etc/crypttab entry on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, encryption, swap

I have been following the following guides:
http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~anqixu/blog/index.php/2018/06/20/install-18-04-on-encrypted-partitions-xps15-cuda/
[How can I install Ubuntu encrypted with LUKS with dual-boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot/293029#293029)

I have created a 4G Swap Partition on the encrypted LVM partition as per the latter link however not sure of the entry to use in /etc/crypttab file.

If I run:

```
blkid | grep swap

/dev/mapper/vgroot-lvswap: UUID="12345678987654321" TYPE=swap
```

Does the entry need to be

```
vgroot-lvswap UID=12345678987654321 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is valid for entry in the `/etc/crypttab` but update your `UID` to `UUID`

```
vgroot-lvswap  UUID="12345678987654321" /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

And also make sure the name `vgroot-lvswap` is the name you used when you ran `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen .... name_of_device_mapper`!

Comment: Thanks with the slight adjustment things seem to be running nicely now.