# Problem installing luks to sdb2 dual boot

Tags: luks

Been following the instructions given in this askubuntu answer [How can I install Ubuntu encrypted with LUKS with dual-boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot)

I can get as far as step # 7: `vcreate -l 100%FREE -n mint_root vgmint`

When i get `Logical  Volume "mint_root" already exists in group "vgmint"`

Ive been following the instructions to the T but for changing my partition labels.

Id ask the person whos answer im following but lack the whatever to comment.

In response to comment: actually im installing ubuntu. Just coppied the wrong command. It happens to be the same command for mint as for ubuntu. Kind of unfortunate that such a thing would be nitpicked and i dont think OP of the thorough answer im refering should remove his complete example of dual booting.

Comment: As far as I understand your going to install Linux Mint which is off-topic here. Your question might get closed for this reason. But I left a comment with a link to your question under the answer you're refering to.

Comment: There is nothing nitpicked. We have some rules on this site, a question can be off-topic, an answer (or a part of it) can be off-topic too. As you see, I have neither voted to close your question nor have I edited this answer in any way, just left a comment with a suggestion to edit the answer, not to remove it completely. Please read carefully and take care your wording.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the answer you are referring to I was not very clear. Both step 6 and 7 are the same thing. You only need to run step 6 or step 7. I rewrote these steps so it will be clear for you, you only need to run one of them. Now, the old step 7 does not exist and the whole process has one less step.