# Does Ubuntu encrypt whole disk including Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, encryption, windows-10

Does Ubuntu encrypt whole disk including Windows 10? Or should I first use BitLocker on Windows?

Comment: Encrypting Windows via Ubuntu would make it unbootable. Encrypt each OS on its own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Ubuntu encrypted with LUKS with dual-boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot)