# Small usable disk space on encrypted drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, encryption

I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot) to dual boot encrypted Ubuntu 18.04 (though on separate physical drives and I skipped making a swap partition). I am now finding the mapped partition I was using only has 8GB of space (confirmed with `df -h`), even though it was a clean 500GB drive and `gparted` and `lsblk` say it has 474GB.

When the 8GB of free space was used up I got errors saying there was no space left.

How can I access what should be the remaining free space?

**Update 1**:
Here is the screenshot of gparted
[gparted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXoZ9.jpg)

Comment: Please use gparted to list your partitions and update your question with the screen shot, I don't think you followed that the instructions accordingly

Comment: added the screenshot.