# Ubuntu 18.04 full disk encryption on different disk or partition

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, encryption

How can I use disk encryption with my Ubuntu 18.04 installation if I want to keep my windows os on the same drive?

I've an nvm hard disk with Windows on it, I've created a partition for Ubuntuv but during the instalation when I check something else and I set up my ubuntu partitions, I don't get the option to encrypt it. And if I select Erase disk and install ubuntu, it doesn't give me the option to select a different drive.

Is there anyway to accomplish it without having to remove windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Ubuntu encrypted with LUKS with dual-boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot)

Comment: Sems quite complicated ... Read not only the accepted answer, there is a lot of information.