# Ubuntu install with mdadm and multiple luks partitions

Tags: boot, system-installation, raid, luks, mdadm

Given 3 identical drives partitioned for an ubuntu 20.04 install as follows (`swap` and `/home` are on separate luks volumes to share with another Linux install on sda3/4)

| Partition | Format | Mount Point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /dev/sda1 | ext4 | /boot |
| /dev/sda2 | luks/ext4 | / |
| /dev/sda3 |  | (Unused) |
| /dev/sda4 |  | (Unused) |
| /dev/sda5 | luks/swap | swap |
| /dev/sdb | RAID 1 Member |  |
| /dev/sdc | RAID 1 Member |  |
| /dev/md0p1 | luks/ext4 | /home |

1. This [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot) is great for setting up luks, but only uses a single encrypted volume for `/` and `swap`. Is there a way to configure `/etc/crypttab` so that a single password is required to unlock `/dev/sda2` which in turn will contain keys for unlocking `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/md0p1` automatically instead of entering 3 passwords on boot?
2. If RAID1 is setup across `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` to create `/dev/md0` with `mdadm` before entering the ubuntu installer, how can ubuntu be configured to assemble the RAID volume on boot for mounting `/home`?

Comment: Which version of Fedora and any other distro are you using? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1365389/edit) and add this information.

Comment: And which version of Ubuntu are you using with Fedora?

Answer (score 0):

1. For each luks volume, generate a new keyfile in `/etc/luks-keys`, add it to the luks volume header with `cryptsetup luksAddKey`, and add path to the key file to `/etc/crypttab` entry for the volume.
2. Couldn't figure this out in the live boot or installer. Ended up being much easier to install without a designated `/home` mount point, then boot into new ubuntu install and configure things from there. I.e. set up mdadm array, [configure assembly on boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/new-raid-array-will-not-auto-assemble-leads-to-boot-problems), and add it to `/etc/fstab` as the `/home` mount point.