# cryptsetup not recognizing `tries` option from `/etc/crypttab`

Tags: 22.04, cryptsetup

I've successfully set up Ubuntu (Kubuntu 22.04, to be more precise) as a secondary OS, next to Windows 10, on a LUKS-encrypted drive. (Single BTRFS partition in LUKS container)

I've not done this before, so it took me a few tries to get it to work. It's booting fine now, but anytime it asks me for the passphrase, I see a warning below the input field:

`Ignoring unknown option: tries`

This is what my `etc-crypttab` looks like:

```
# <target name> <source device>         <key file>      <options>
luks-<UUID> UUID=<UUID> none luks,tries=6
```

The line is obviously being read (also evidenced by the fact that if I edit it and change it to something wrong, I get no access at all to the LUKS partition), but something cannot deal with `tries`.

I'd really like to get more than the default 3 tries because my passphrase is pretty long, and I have to enter it on keyboards with different layouts, which means I have to type it "double-blind" (without seeing what I typed on-screen, but also without the correct labels on the keys I'm pressing). I've already run into the 3-retries limit once, which is how I know that the option is definitely being ignored.

#### What I tried so far:

Funny enough, the option seems to be completely congruent with the Debian crypttab manpage. The Debian manpage carries a warning it (the manpage, that is) is specific for Debian, and recommends also consulting the [systemd version](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/crypttab.html) (and provides the link). The systemd version of the manpage also lists ´tries=n` as a valid option.

I had some hunch about having gotten the use of commas or spaces wrong, but any variation I tried either does nothing or breaks the setup.

My original attempt at setting up `/etc/crypttab` was based on an [older how-to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293028/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-encrypted-with-luks-with-dual-boot) which uses the option `retry` -- but changing that also failed, and there are recent comments in the linked thread saying that `retry` is not (no longer?) recognized, and `tries` should be used.